# How to find insertions/deletions by comparing hashes quickly?

Tags: algorithm, hash

I want to create a hash of a file such that if the file is changed I can determine what parts of the file changed. The problem is that if a byte is removed or added, all subsequent hashes change too, therefore I need to iterate per byte through all hashes. This however can be expensive so I am looking for a hash which doesnt require that I recompute the entire hash start to finish but rather lets me undo one byte and then add another byte.

Pseudocode:

```
string getFileDiffHash(file){
    string result = "";
    for each (512 bytes in file){
        result += hash(bytes);
    }
}

string getFileDiff(file, diffHash){
    string result = "";
    for each (hash size bytes in diffHash){ //yes this would be in a hash table ideally, but hey, this is pseudocode
        string current_hash = "";
        for (i = 0; i < file_size(file); i++){
            if (current_hash.size > hash_size){
                current_hash = undo_hash(current_hash, file[i-hash_size]);
            }
            current_hash = add_hash(current_hash, file[i]);
            if (current_hash.size == hash_size && bytes == current_hash){
                result += "+"+diffHash+":"+i;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any idea on what sort of hash would be suited to 'undo_hash' and 'add_hash'?

Comment: Can you please explain a close vote and not simply close it? This is a relevant programming question.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do better. The question is very unclear. Add some explanation and show examples.

Comment: Much better. Look up "rolling hash", I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: What sorts of edits are you trying to track?  Are you looking for individual insertions/deletions, or groups of insertions and deletions?  Also, is there a reason that you cannot use a standard tool like `diff` to do this?

Comment: @templatetypedef the problem with diff is that it requires that you have the before and after. I only have the after and whatever hash i choose to keep from the before. I dont want to keep an entire copy of the before because it is too big.

Comment: Could you compute the `diff` and then store that instead of a hash, or perhaps a compressed version of the `diff`?

Comment: @templatetypedef no, because you cant look into the future

Comment: @chacham15- I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Can you clarify?

Comment: It sounds that you might need an error correction code. algorithm.

Comment: @templatetypedef a file gets changed by someone else without your knowledge at any time. you get notified AFTER it changes. figure out what changed in the file without having a backup copy of the file. jbaylina, rolling hashes are what I was looking for.

Comment: Why you don't do like Dropbox (and probably others) do: they divide the file into chunks and compute the individual hash of these chunks (like you did), but then they store index of the chunk and the hash in a database. When the file is changed, all you have to do is to calculate each hash of the chunks again and compare with the one previously stored. Is this an option?

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira the algorithm i described above IS the dropbox algorithm (rsync). I just found that out after the link provided. You have to do this rolling hash business because an insert will change the byte boundary of all hashes afterwards so you cant just do a lookup.

Comment: @chacham15- Ah, I see.  I thought that you were able to intercept file reads/writes and react to them; I didn't realize that this was after the fact.

Comment: @chacham15 Sorry, but I completely disagree with you because I have implemented it at the exactly way I described during my graduation. Maybe I haven't been clear enough about the algorithm. I implemented in C# and used SHA256 algorithm to do the hashing of the chunks. Used an SQLITE database to store and to perform the chunk and file lookup, and serialization at the network level. If you wish more info, I can provide more detailed info about the algorithm.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira no, you were clear, just that algorithm is suboptimal: imagine you have the sequence A,B,C,D and you compute the has for every 2 bytes. You get hash(A,B), hash(C,D). Then say you insert another letter E in the middle to get A, E, B, C, D. Now you have: hash(A, E), hash(B, C), hash(D). None of those hashes are going to match despite the fact that you have mostly the same data. This is why you need the rolling hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Interjay's comment was correct, I need a rolling hash. Furthermore, the algorithm I describe here is similar to what rsync does (and Dropbox by extension).

Answer (score 0):

If you can have a hash of length log2(N) bytes, you can use a [Hamming code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code). If it must be shorter, then a [Low-density parity-check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-density_parity-check_code) code would do the job.